# Find the number of transitions for certain value within a list of values

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table include "ID" and "Values", and wanted to know how many times does value "A" jumped into another values like below

| ID | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | C |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | B |

Expected Result:

| ID | Values | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 1 | C | 0 |
| 1 | C | 0 |
| 1 | C | 0 |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | A | 0 |
| 2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 2 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 2 | C | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 |

The final table should be like this:

| ID | Number of Transitions |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

Comment: What dictates "jumping"? Is there a date column?

Answer (score 1):

You just need `LEAD()` to look at the next value:

```sql
select id, values, lead(value) over(partition by id) next_value
from table
```

Then you can compare `next_value` with `values`, and apply an `iff(value='A' and next_value!='A', 1, 0)`.

Then just `SUM()` or `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also treat this as a `regexp` problem where you want to count how many times a given pattern occurs for each id. The missing piece in your question is -what column dictates the order in which the values appear for each id? You'll need that for either of the solutions

```
select id, regexp_count(listagg(val,',') within group (order by ordering_col), 'A,[^A]')
from t
group by id;
```